# How to detect the edge of a window in python

Tags: python, python-turtle

I was trying to make a worm AI thingy that moves around using python turtle and , but I don’t know how to detect the edge of the turtle window for it do evade it. pls help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share more information on what you have tried so far.

Comment: and also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: left boder: `warm_x < -width`, right border `warm_x > +width`, etc. ? You have to only know `width` - `width = turtle.window_width()/2`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get window's width

```
WIDTH = screen.window_width()
```

and then turtle may have position `x` in range `-WIDTH/2 ... WIDTH/2` and you can do

```
x, y = turtle.pos()

if x > WIDTH/2:
    turtle.setx(-WIDTH/2)

if x < -WIDTH/2:
    turtle.setx(WIDTH/2)
```

Similar you can do for position `y` and `window_height()`.

---

Minimal working example:

```
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
WIDTH = screen.window_width()

t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.speed(0)

while True:
    t.forward(5)
    x, y = t.pos()
    if x > WIDTH/2:
        t.setx(-WIDTH/2)
    screen.update()
```

---

**EDIT:**

More complex version with 10 turtles which move like in game [Asteroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroids_(video_game))

```
import turtle

def check_border(t):
    x, y = t.pos()

    if x > WIDTH/2:
        t.setx(-WIDTH/2)
        #x -= WIDTH
        #t.setx(x)
    if x < -WIDTH/2:
        t.setx(WIDTH/2)
        #x += WIDTH
        #t.setx(x)
        
    if y > HEIGHT/2:
        t.sety(-HEIGHT/2)
        #y -= HEIGHT
        #t.sety(y)
    if y < -HEIGHT/2:
        t.sety(HEIGHT/2)
        #y += HEIGHT
        #t.sety(y)
    
# --- main --

screen = turtle.Screen()
WIDTH  = screen.window_width()
HEIGHT = screen.window_height()

all_turtles = []
for angle in range(0, 360, 36):
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.penup()
    t.speed(0)
    t.left(angle)
    all_turtles.append(t)

while True:

    for t in all_turtles:    
        t.forward(15)
        check_border(t)
        
    screen.update()
```